# Prevent Cygwin from clearing terminal window

Tags: cmd.exe, cygwin

I start a new `cmd.exe` and run Cygwin like this:

```
C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat
```

Then I type `exit`. Cygwin now clears the whole terminal window. Is there a way to prevent this?

(I cannot use `miniterm.exe` because I am calling Cygwin from a batch file and Cygwin has to run in the same console window.)

Comment: Cygwin by itself doesn't do anything in this way. The standard Cygwin.bat file just creates an interactive bash login shell. With `exit`, you terminate the shell, and on shell termination a certain set of files are executed - this is described in the section _INVOCATION_ in the bash man page. As far I am aware, this is the file `~/.bash_logout`. This file can indeed contain a command for clearing the screen.

Comment: Another experiment you could do is to edit Cygwin.bat and add a `PAUSE` command at the end. This allows you to see, whether clearing the screen comes from bash, or from Windows CMD.

Answer (score 0):

The Cygwin Setup program installs a script at `/etc/bash.bash_logout` that calls `/usr/bin/clear`. Remove that call from that file.